# cat: /dev/ttyS0: Input/output error

Tags: kernel, tty, serial-port

I am unable to write to or read from `/dev/ttyS0`

```
# cat /dev/ttyS0                
cat: /dev/ttyS0: Input/output error
```

the device exists, and root has permissions.

```
# ls -lAhF /dev/ttyS0
crw------- 1 root root 4, 64 Nov 18 12:09 /dev/ttyS0

# setserial -g /dev/ttyS0 
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4

# dmesg | egrep -i 'serial|ttys'
[    1.243271] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[ 2703.151301] ttyS0: LSR safety check engaged!

# cat /proc/devices | grep tty  
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
```

I have serial enabled in my kernel:

```
# grep SERIAL config
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_NR_UARTS=1
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS=1
CONFIG_SERIAL_CORE=y
```

**What do I have to do to make serial work ?**

Comment: Did you get an answer? Are you running everything as `root` (not a good idea, we can help with this)?

Answer (score 0):

Serial devices require a bunch of configuration (baud rate, stop bits, start bits, parity, etc.) to work properly.  Generally, trying to access them with cat/echo isn't going to work right away, and is also a not a very good way to use them.

What is your use case with the serial device?  Can you use an application like [`minicom`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-minicom/) (see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35gdWj94-lQ) or [`microcom`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/microcom.1.html) to access your device and provide the necessary configuration?  If not, try to use [`stty`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) to read/write your serial configuration from/to the device before trying echo/cat.

If you have experience with python, I recommend trying the [PySerial](https://devtut.github.io/python/python-serial-communication-pyserial.html) (see: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) library.  It will allow you to programmatically set the serial configuration, and then call read/write on the serial port object.